# Nativescript Firebase - some properties of objects are missed

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

I'm using the following plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase allowing to access Firebase from Nativescript applicaiton. 
For some reasons, when I do a query request to get my objects, some properties of the json objects are missed. 
Below the query :

```
return firebase.query(
    data => {
        if(data.value) {
            Object.keys(data.value).forEach(key => {
                this.results.push(data.value[key]); // Here I dont get exactly the JSON, some properties disapears.....
            }
        }
    }, "/ads/", 
    { orderBy: { type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.KEY }})
    .then(result => { return result; })
);
```

My database

[image]

Properties of type number are not loaded (totalProduct and state).
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I find out that your forEach miss a ')'.
After modified, everything is fine. All of the JSON properties still exist.